# Extract absolute coordinates from reference system

Tags: qgis, coordinates, extract

[image]

How can i set a local reference system to get relative points coordinates from absolute coordinates?

example :

point 1 : X = 0   Y = 0
point 2 : X = 100 Y = 0
point 3 : X = 100 Y = 100
point 4 : X= 0  Y = 100

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401579/88814

Comment: yes and no. I am not trying to assign new coordinates but to convert the existing ones in a local reference. Furthermore, it would be good if the solution could work for other shapes, simple and complex.

Comment: Are your example points the intended output data? Are you wanting to convert coordinates from a projected coordinate system (UTM or similar) to a local grid where you define the origin point?

Comment: Yes, that´s the idea. Better if it will be also applicable to irregular polygons.